# find records that are not present in another dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe1

```
date          username          city          sales
2021-03-01    Steve            Florida        1000
2021-03-01    Steve            Washington     2000
2021-03-02    Steve            Alabama        2500
2021-03-02    Steve            Kansas city    500
2021-03-02    John K           Alabama        2000
```

dataframe2 contains

```
date         username       city              email
2021-03-01    Steve         Washington     steve7@xyz.com
2021-03-02    Steve         New york       steve7@xyz.com
2021-03-02    John K        New York       johnk8@xyz.com
```

Expected result (returns the records from df2 that are not in df1)

```
date       username       city        email
2021-03-02  Steve        New York    steve7@xyz.com
2021-03-02  John K       New York    johnk8@xyz.com
```

How could I return this result?

Comment: I don't understand your output. Why the first row of the expected output?

Comment: if you consider the `date username city` columns in the df2, these records are not present in df1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an outer join and use `indicator=True`:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
result = result[result['_merge'] == 'right_only']
result = result.drop(columns=['_merge'])
```

If you want to use an equivalent one-liner:

```
result = (pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
            .query('_merge == "right_only"')
            .drop(columns=['_merge']))
```